# I tried to fill in the blank by any means but it was wrong

Tags: image, css

Here is your exercise: 
Fill in the correct value of margin attribute to make "img" element adherent to the left side, and approxiamately 10px away from the right side

```
img {
float: right;
margin:;//here is blank
```

Comment: That's not a question Loi!, please explain what was wrong. There are some sintax errors in your code, is that all?

Comment: no, i need fill in the blank with value make  make "img" element adherent to the left side, and approxiamately 10px away from the right side

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here... if you're trying to float right, but leave a 10px margin on the right, it has to be like this... (this is what I'm understanding from your "question".

```
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

Also, commenting in CSS is not like this: `//here is blank.`

It should be `/*here is blank*/`

Hope that makes sense.

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?random">
```

Comment: Then your question is not very clear. Please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: it means the correct value of margin attribute to make "img" element adherent to the left side, and approximately 10px away from the right side.I was tried everythings but it not work

Comment: You want the image to float left? And be at least 10px from the right side? I updated my answer above, which matches what you're asking.

Comment: Then, you need to rewrite your question. In your original question, you stated **"adherent to the left side, and approxiamately `10px` away from the right side"**